# Selectively updating the multilevel column name of a dataframe (python), a column with a specific text to have a particular name

Tags: python-3.x, multiple-columns, rename, multi-index

I have a multi level column dataframe, where first two columns have text in level 1 (level 2 empty)and remaining column have date in level 2 (level 1 text).

```
S1  S2        _id                  _id
              07-08-2016 00:00     14-08-2016 00:00
ABC ABC1      22071                19474
CDE CDE1      17                   3
```

I tried something like this, but it is not working

```
pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(s1,s1) if isinstance(s1, datetime.date)  else (s2) for s1,s2 in df.columns],names=.columns.names)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried an alternate way

```
df.columns = [(s2) if s1 == '_id' else (s1) for s1,s2 in df.columns]
```

I applied the if condition on string, but the ideal solution would be to identify dateformat in the multilevel column name